# Displaying all products categories in a drop down menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Working with WP and WooCommerce product categories. I'm attempting to display all product categories in a drop down menu. I have this working, however I need the hierarchy to also be displayed. For example Apple is a Sub Category of Fruit.

So I want the display to look like this:

```
Fruit    
-Apple   
-Pear
```

But it currently looks like this:

```
 Fruit    
 Apple   
 Pear
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
$args = array(
            'number'     => $number,
            'orderby'    => $orderby,
            //'name' => 'select_name',
            //'id' => 'select_name',
            'order'      => $order,
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'include'    => $ids,
            'hierarchical' => true
            );

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
```

My markup:

```
<select name='categorylist'>    
   <?php foreach($product_categories as $cat) {
      echo "<option value='{$cat->name}'>{$cat->name}</option>"; 
   } ?>
```

I know it is possible to set the hierarchy like this for sub categories. Could anyone suggest what I can do to my $args array to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: You just need to check if a particular `$product_categories` element has has a `'hierarchical' == true` value. I assume you can query this.

Comment: I'm pulling back up to a couple of hundred categories here so it needs to be set on the fly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)

```
$args = array(
    'selected'           => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => 1, 
    'taxonomy'           => 'product_cat',
)
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```